# Gradle + TestKit + JaCoco: file locked exception

Tags: gradle

I am trying to integrate Gradle TestKit with JaCoCo. I am using this plugin
https://github.com/koral--/jacoco-gradle-testkit-plugin

Which creates gradle properties (in test-projects including my plugin) such as:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs:-javaagent:{someDirsHere}/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.1/9aa64427abccf89cfc44a72acaf9d288d80deb8b/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar=destfile={someDirsHere}/build/jacoco/test-integration.exec
```

JaCoCO in main project is set up this way:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
    executionData = rootProject.files("${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec", "${buildDir}/jacoco/test-integration.exec") 
}
```

But it seems that something keeps lock on the test-integration.exec file. (If I remove it everything works ok)

Exception is (**java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file**):

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':quality-plugin:jacocoTestReport' property 'executionData' during up-to-date check.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.fingerprintTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:360)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.ensureSnapshotBeforeTask(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:162)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository$RerunTaskArtifactState.isUpToDate(ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.snapshot(CachingFileHasher.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.hash(CachingFileHasher.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.SplitFileHasher.hash(SplitFileHasher.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:179)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshotAndCache(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:165)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshotAndCache(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:149)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.access$200(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$2.create(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$2.create(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:129)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:258)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:206)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractPathOnlyFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractPathOnlyFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.fingerprintTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:358)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.doHash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:38)
        ... 53 more
```

Is there something I am missing?
I am running it on Windows, Java 10.2, Gradle 4.10.1

Answer (score 0):

when reviewing the `org.gradle.jvmargs`, it reads ...

```
destfile={someDirsHere}/build/jacoco/test-integration.exec
```

which will request exclusive access for writing that file; which locks it.

not passing the argument and using the default configuration should work:

```
task generateJacocoIntegrationTestKitProperties(type: GenerateJaCoCoTestKitProperties) {
    destinationFile = file('integration.exec')
}
```

with a `jacoco.gradle` (most likely) alike:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
    executionData = files()
}
```

also see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aalmiray/e6f54aa4b3803be0bcac), which appears relevant, concerning the aggregation of sub-project coverage tests:

```
subprojects.findAll { subproject ->
    subproject.pluginManager.hasPlugin('java') && subproject.pluginManager.hasPlugin('jacoco')
}.each { subproject ->
    executionData += subproject.tasks.jacocoTestReport.executionData
}

executionData = files(executionData.findAll {
    it.exists()
})
```

for a single project, this makes little sense, but when having sub-projects, it does.